# Bookkeeping vs using pointers to check if member variable is initialized

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class `Action` that holds a member variable for each of my device input types.  They are initialized after construction, but I make no guarantee they'll be initialized.

```
class Action
{
private:
   KeyboardButton mKeyboardButton;
   MouseButton    mMouseButton;
   JoystickButton mJoystickButton;
}
```

The issue is these three classes do not provide a way to verify if they are initialized.  I could do some bookkeeping and store a boolean.  However, this seems error prone.  I could make them pointers and then compare verse nullptr.  However, I have always avoided pointers unless necessary.

What are the trade-offs between the two approaches I have suggested?

Comment: The design looks flawed. How about three classes - `KeyboardAction`, etc, derived from the `Action` class.

Comment: If those variables are not pointers (or references) then each action will have its own instance of the keyboard/mouse/joystick, I'm not sure if that's what you want... As for detecting if they are initialised, using a boolean doesn't seem so error prone, do they get init'ed after constructed or something?

Comment: @T.Kiley If there's additional initialization after construction, this is part of the objects state.  (A good example of this is `std::filebuf::is_open`.)  There shouldn't be a need for an additional variable; this should be part of the visible state of each object.

Comment: @T.Kiley I've updated my post, because it was misleading how I referred to my member variables.  They are initialized after construction.  Also, I make no guarantee all three will ever be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna assume each `Action` needs it's own instances of `Keyboard`, `Mouse` and `Joystick`, because if you wanted to share them between `Action`s you would have to use pointers. So the question is - does it make sense to have an `Action` where at least on of the three is not initialized?

If the answer is "no" - each `Action` must have all of the three - you can just initialize them in `Action'`s constructor and never worry about them not being initialized.

If the answer is "yes" - use pointers! If you make sure to allocate-initialize or nullify them in the constructor, to clone them in the copy-constructor and the assignment operator overload, and to `delete` them in the destructor - there shouldn't be any problems!

PS. I've assumed each `Action` needs it's own instances of the three, but if it's possible to share them and you don't do that just because you don't like pointers, you should consider sharing them with pointers.

Comment: The answer is yes, there is no guarantee all three member variables will be initialized.  I will reimplement my solution using unique_ptrs and see how it works.